# networked GHCi API like nREPL?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Does GHCi have a networked API like Clojure's nREPL?

It would make tooling easier e.g. interactive evaluation within Emacs.

Answer (score 3):

There's [hdevtools](https://github.com/bitc/hdevtools). "Persistent GHC powered background server for FAST Haskell development tools" ... 
"Communication with the background process is done through a unix socket file. The default name is .hdevtools.sock, in the current directory. This allows you to use hdevtools with multiple projects simultaneously, without the background processes getting in the way of each other."